# Listen for POST event with specific content using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I've got a scenario where an AngularJS site is not loading any jQuery (aside from the inclued jQLite) and I need to listen for events with specific parameters.

I can't edit any of the source, but the event in the dev console shows that it is a POST event to a specific URL: https://example.com/ajax/leadgen

And I need to listen for when this POST event contains specific parameters like:
leadType =  25
pageID = abcd

I've been looking into various options using addEventListener but I can't figure out how to apply that to this scenario.

Comment: that isn't an event, it's an ajax request, and you cannot listen for it to complete unless you have access to the XHR that generated it.

Comment: You would need to override the XMLHttpRequest send() method.

Comment: @epascarello Or override Angular's $http service, assuming that's what the application is using.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the XMLHttpRequest object to be able to listen for the call being made.

```
//Reference the original methods
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

//override open
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
   this._url = arguments[1];  //set the url we are opening
   this._open.apply(this,arguments);  //call original open event with arguments
};

//override send
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
   //This is where your logic would need to live.
   console.log(this._url, arguments ? arguments[0] : null);  //read the url we set and the arguments passed into send
   this._send.apply(this, arguments); //call original send event with arguments
};

//Test making an Ajax request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", window.location.href, true);
xhr.send("a=b");
```